# How do I get the country from this JSON string?

Tags: php, json

Here's my string which I've captured from an API using CURL:

```
{
  "ip": "8.8.8.8",
  "hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.3860,-122.0838",
  "org": "AS15169 Google Inc.",
  "postal": "94040"
}
```

How do I get the country code? This is what I've been trying and it just returns the entire json string:

```
$json = json_decode($json_raw, true);
    $country = $json['country'];
```

Comment: i can't see any problem here as long as you have assigned the correct value to $json_raw variable.

Comment: Could try [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to make sure the issue isn't with your JSON in some way

Comment: your following correct way, it's fine for getting value from json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your value in in an object, use `->` to access.

```
<?php
$a = '{
  "ip": "8.8.8.8",
  "hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.3860,-122.0838",
  "org": "AS15169 Google Inc.",
  "postal": "94040"
}';
$decode = json_decode($a);

echo $decode->country;// this line
```

See demo [**here**](https://eval.in/483732)

As `Surace` said, even this should work fine

```
<?php
    $a = '{
       "ip": "8.8.8.8",
       "hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
       "city": "Mountain View",
       "region": "California",
       "country": "US",
       "loc": "37.3860,-122.0838",
       "org": "AS15169 Google Inc.",
       "postal": "94040"
  }';
$decode = json_decode($a,true);

echo $decode['country'];
```

See demo [**here**](https://eval.in/483749)

Comment: isn't it the same as what op is doing, instead of object she is passing true parameter which parses json in assoc.

Comment: I get an odd error "Trying to get property of non-object on line 61". I think for some reason it's not creating an object?

Comment: did u try with the demo??

Comment: @Amy the only problem i can see in your code is that $json_raw does not have correct json or empty, other than that your code is just fine, you are trying to format json as assoc array and in this example it is being parsed as object, no difference at all

Comment: @Surace didnt notice that.

Comment: I'm not ignoring you, trying to figure out why it's not working with my code and then I'll accept if it works :)

Comment: @AmyNeville, both the methods should work fine. I have provided demo for both. Have a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

as you decode json to php format it returns result as object so you have to use object syn text to access its properties. 
**replace**

```
  $decode = json_decode($a,true);
    $country = $json['country'];
```

**with**

```
 $decode = json_decode($a);
     $country = $json->country;
```

Comment: but you pass the true as second param then it decodes the json as assoc.

Comment: i am not getting you..

Comment: Op is passing true as a second parameter on json_decode function which returns the output as an associative array not a object so your solution will throw exception.

Comment: thank you man...for suggesting..

Comment: oh so I shouldn't use 'true' then?

Comment: You can use true if you want, but why bother converting a perfectly good object to an array.

Comment: yes mam or if you want to use true then can access country by using $json['country']

Answer (score 1):

I could be missing something but I see no reason for your code is not working for you.
You can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with the true option like you did to use the returned value as an array.

```
<?php
$json_raw = '{
"ip": "8.8.8.8",
"hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
"city": "Mountain View",
"region": "California",
"country": "US",
"loc": "37.3860,-122.0838",
"org": "AS15169 Google Inc.",
"postal": "94040"
}';

$json = json_decode($json_raw, true);
echo $country = $json['country'];
```

You can check here: https://eval.in/483744